# Dynamic Pivot Table - How to add the columns generated to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a dynamic pivot query which transposes rows to columns. At the moment I have all the data in one table but can separate it if two separate tables is easier.

I only need some the column ChargeNames pivoted as such (with the related charges included)  Is it possible to only pivot part of the table and join the new Pivot table onto the source table?

Or could I create a new table with the required data and pivot it, and join it up to another table?

Apologies if it sounds somewhat confusing

**Source table with all data**
[image]

**Pivot table (column for pivot is Chargenames)**
[image]

**The Code - Declaring and populating table**

```
--Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE ##tempGetPaymentAnalysisByMember
(
    MemberID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Surname NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CategoryName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    InvoiceID INT,
    ChargeNames NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ChargeAmount INT,
    TotalAmount INT
)

--Populate the table

INSERT INTO ##tempGetPaymentAnalysisByMember(MemberID, FirstName, Surname, CategoryName, InvoiceID, ChargeNames, ChargeAmount, TotalAmount)

SELECT Member.ID, Member.FirstName, Member.Surname, Category.Name, Invoice.ID, ChargeType.Name, Charge.Amount, Invoice.Amount

FROM dbo.Member, dbo.Category, dbo.Invoice, dbo.ChargeType, dbo.Charge
    WHERE Category.ID = Member.CategoryID
    AND Member.ID = Invoice.MemberID
    AND Charge.ChargeTypeID = ChargeType.ID
    AND Charge.InvoiceID = Invoice.ID

--Test select to check if data is correct
SELECT * FROM ##tempGetPaymentAnalysisByMember
```

**The Pivot Query**

```
    SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
       +QUOTENAME(ChargeNames)
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ChargeNames FROM ##tempGetPaymentAnalysisByMember) AS ChargeName

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
'SELECT ' + @ColumnName +
' FROM ##tempGetPaymentAnalysisByMember
    PIVOT(MIN(ChargeAmount)
        FOR ChargeNames IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PivotTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working without the need for an extra table.

I was able to join two tables together and perform a PIVOT on just a select amount of the columns which before I didn't know you could do.

I understand the code below needs to be cleaned up a bit to stop possible SQL injection attacks, but I'll leave that till I get the whole program working.

```
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
           +QUOTENAME(ChargeName)
    FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT ChargeName FROM ##chargesTable) AS ChargeName

     SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
    'SELECT MemberID, FirstName, Surname, CategoryName, TotalAmount, ' + @ColumnName +  
    ' FROM ##chargesTable
        PIVOT(MIN(ChargeAmount)
            FOR ChargeName IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PivotTable
    ORDER BY MemberID'



    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```